# Compare two images, and return the rate of similarity (e.g., in %)

Tags: computer-vision

I am looking for a program that can compare two images, and return the rate of similarity (e.g., in %).

Any license, price, and operating system is fine. I mostly interested in the quantity of the image similarity algorithm.

Comment: What do you define as similarity? (Roughly the) same colo(u)r pixel in (roughly) the same place?

Comment: @Mawg ideally, the algorithm should match similarity as judged by humans, which I am aware is partly subjective

Comment: Lol - make that ***entirely*** subjective :-) Can we try to define it? Roughly the same shapes/colo(u)rs in roughly the same places? I am hoping to get am answer to this question, btw

Comment: Similarity as judged by humans sounds like a difficult research problem, not something you're going to find an accurate shrink-wrapped tool for.

Comment: @Kodiologist some relatively subjective take such as automated summarization or content aware filling have some decently well packaged code/program taking care of it.

Comment: In artificial intelligence, "similarity" is a specific technical term and there are algorithms to measure it. You might get some value by posting a question on that SE site.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the morphing distance as calculated by https://github.com/kallaballa/Poppy (I am the author)

e.g. when running poppy as follows, the last line denotes the distance between the circle and square image.

[image: image of a black filled circle]
[image: image of a black filled square]

`src/poppy -n images/circle.png images/square.png`

Which gives 0.0257155 in this example.

When comparing something more similar, like e.g. two faces:

[image: Picture of a face]
[image: Picture of another face]

`src/poppy -n images/some1.png images/some2.png`

It gives 0.00411874, which is way lower.

Comment: You are the author of this tool, right? A rule of this site is that you must disclose any affiliation, so please state it clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have developed an [image comparison algorithm](https://vitali-fedulov.github.io/similar.pictures/algorithm-for-perceptual-image-comparison.html) for near duplicate search, which you can try online on the web-site. The corresponding program *func EucMetric* ([Github code](https://github.com/vitali-fedulov/images3/blob/master/similarity.go)) returns 3 similarity metrics (one per color channel).

Current implementation is relatively strict on position/rotation/distortion etc. But by adding a sliding window with scale/position variations, it is possible to apply this algorithm to sub-regions, so that you can get a cumulative metric based on similarity of image parts.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the difference of two images using imagemagick.

> Use ImageMagick® to create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images.
>   It can read and write images in a variety of [formats](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) (over 200)
>   including PNG, JPEG, GIF, HEIC, TIFF, [DPX](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/motion-picture.php), [EXR](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/high-dynamic-range.php), WebP, Postscript, PDF,
>   and SVG. Use ImageMagick to resize, flip, mirror, rotate, distort,
>   shear and transform images, adjust image colors, apply various special
>   effects, or draw text, lines, polygons, ellipses and Bézier curves.

[imagemagick homepage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)

It works fine on Windows. See this [answer at stackoverflow.com about comparing two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229535/measure-similarity-of-two-images-in-java-or-imagemagick#29231107) If the output is "1161" it's 50%. See @Mark Setchell's comment about his own answer.

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%G IN ('magick.exe compare -metric ae PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE\a.jpg PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE\b.jpg null:') DO @SET n=%%G 
echo %percent%
```

Save this file as "percent.bat" or whatever you like in the same directory of magick.exe. Run it on command line. (I had to add "magick.exe" above code)

Virustotal.Com results for executables are fine, I only tested setup program and magick.exe